# Conventions for package-level settings or options?

Tags: r, r-package, cran

A function displays an informative message the first time it runs per R session. However, experienced users may want this message to not appear, ever.

I considered simply setting an `options()` when the package is loaded, then if the user *really* doesn't want to see any message, they can set the option value from `TRUE` to `FALSE` at the start of their script.

Are there any established conventions around how package level options should be set?

From my own thinking:

- Try to ensure no overriding of existing options
- Try to ensure the name of the option is not the same as any other option set in any other common package (that could be very confusing to the user)

Are there any other things to consider?

Note: I did find [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/settings/vignettes/settings.html), which looks promising, but unfortunately it seems to return a 404 *not found*.

Comment: People can use `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` or `suppressMessages()` if they really want to silence messages. Just make sure you are rendering your messages with `message()` rather than `print()` or `cat()` or anything else. No need to invent some alternative settings.

Comment: @MrFlick good thinking. I like it. But I'm still keen to at least entertain the idea of an option(). The reason being, I'm worried the message will annoy experienced users, and burdening them with things like `suppressMessages()` could be as annoying to them as the message itself. I know I'm being pedantic, so I'll leave it as-is (and let users `suppressMessages` as you suggest) if nothing better is suggested, but I figure it doesn't hurt to see if there are other ways, just in case there's something else out there. Really appreciate your advice